# How to save data on the server for later use?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created the program for basic calculation and I have to save the users'  previous answers. It is simple addition formula in javascript. When the same person comes back after long time then also it must show the same answer. This means I want to save the answer on my server for that particular person. How can I store all of this data, and access it again when required?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function calculate() {
                a = document.getElementById('num1').value;
                b = document.getElementById('num2').value;
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = Number(a) + Number(b);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id='num1' value="1"/>
        <input id='num2' value='3'/>
        <p id='result'></p>
        <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above example I want to save the users' name and answers on my server. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you using any server side language or just limited to javascript? Because with pure client side javascript you can't save anything on your server other than cookies.

Comment: cookies or localStorage

Comment: Pick a server-side language/framework and more than likely a database and enjoy.

Comment: How do i send the data to database and even receive it? @Jon P

Comment: This is where you need a server side language/framework such as PHP, ASP.net, JSP, Ruby, etc

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that.

you can use form to send data to php or java through get or post methods.

You can store them at client side through cookies but client can delete them anytime.

You can also use ajax if you dont want to refresh your page.

Comment: Can you give me link or tell me how to send and get data by php method as i am poor in php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181733/submitting-a-form-using-php-to-store-information-in-a-database

Comment: Thank's it was a great help.. :)